# Enlace subrayado y que al hacer hover se subraye de nuevo

Tags: javascript, css, botón, animación, hover

Tengo un enlace que hace una animación de subrayarse al hacer hover, hecho con :after y content.

Lo que quiero es que este botón esté subrayado completo por defecto y que al hacer hover se inicie el efecto de subrayado de principio a fin.
Entiendo que debería incluir Javascript para eso.

```
.boton-personalizado{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
color: #1d1d1b;
}
.boton-personalizado:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: -100%;
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background: #1d1d1b;
transition: left .8s;
}
.boton-personalizado:hover:after {
left: 0;
}
.elementor-button-wrapper.elementor-button{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Curiosidad: ¿por qué no usás `text-decoration:underline;`? ¿Y por qué un `button` en lugar de `a`?

Comment: Es que usando text-decoration:underline, no se me "reiniciaría" la animación de subrayado al hacer el hover. Tendría el subrayado fijo y no lo puedo modificar. Y es un enlace (a), igual no lo expresé bien en la pregunta.

Comment: Como tu pregunta es acerca de CSS, podrías agregar un [repro] ejecutable en la pregunta misma, a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`), esto para tener idea de cómo se ve "en vivo" hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un efecto de hover en mi sitio web que es para un formulario de emails, como dices, al presionar una de las opciones, la caja de texto cambia el color del borde, además, está hecho solo con css. Este es el codigo css:

```
    *{margin:0;
      padding:0;
           box-sizing:border-box;}
 body{
      font-family:Arial-Helvetica-sans-serif;
      background-color:#2196f3;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      min-height:100vh;
 }

 .form-content{ background:linear-gradient(
           50deg,
           rgba(40, 42, 55, 1) 50%,
           rgba(40, 42, 55, 1)
      ),
           url(Downloads/bg.jpg);
           background-position:center;
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size: cover;
           padding:50px;
           width:800px;
           border-radius:25px; }

 .form-content h2{

           color:#f4f6f9;
           font-size:32px;
           margin-bottom:25px;}

 form{

           display:flex;
           flex-direction:column;
           width:80%; 
 }

 label{

           font-size:17px;
           color:#959aab;
           margin-bottom:10px;
 }

 input, textarea{

           padding:8px;
           background-color:#333646;
           border:0;
           font-size:15px;
           color:f4f6f9;
           margin-bottom:20px;
           border-radius:10px;
           color:#f4f6f9;
           resize:none;
 }

 :focus{

      outline:1px solid #1e92e9;
 }

 .btn{

      background-color:#1e92e9;
      width:150px;
      align-self:flex-end;
      cursor:pointer;
 }

 .btn:hover{

      background-color:#219bf9;
 } 

 @media(max-width:991px){

      body{
           padding:30px;
      }

      .form-content{
           width:100%;
      }

      form{
           width:100%;
      }
 }
```

Este el HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.56">
     <title>Contáctanos-Un biker enamorado</title>
</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS\email.css">

<div class="form-content">

<h2>FORMULARIO</h2>



<form action="https://formsubmit.co/0ef28e9f06ecec7ab9035df634f33f78" method="POST" />

 <label for="name">Nombre</label>
 <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="name" required>

 <label for="email">Correo o Num. de teléfono</label>
 <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">

 <label for="subject">Asunto</label>
 <input type="text" name="Asunto" id="subject">

 <label for="comments">Escribe tus comentarios</label>
 <textarea name="Comentarios" id="comments" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea>

 <br>

 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Lee [answer]: ¡no olvides explicar tu respuesta! ¿Cómo funciona el código? ¿Qué propiedades son las necesarias para lograr lo que OP busca? Pulsa en [edit] para ampliar tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

se puede solucionar haciendo uso del pseudo elemento ::before con las mismas propiedades que tienes en el ::after pero removiendo el estilo "left: -100%" para que siempre este visible, y de esta forma el que hace la animación entra asta que se hace el hover y así no necesitaras javascript en este caso. te dejo un ejemplo a continuación

```css
.boton-personalizado {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #1d1d1b;
}

.boton-personalizado:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  transition: left .8s;
}

.boton-personalizado::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: rgb(7, 170, 7);
  transition: left .8s;
}

.boton-personalizado:hover:after {
  left: 0;
}

.elementor-button-wrapper.elementor-button {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.56">
  <title>Contáctanos-Un biker enamorado</title>
</head>

<body>
<a class="boton-personalizado">TEST UNDERLINE</a>
</body>

</html>
```